# If $f$ is a complex polynomial such that $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ whenever $|z| = 1$, then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

> Let $f \in \mathbb{C}[z]$ a complex polynomial such that $f(S^1) \subset \mathbb{R},$ where
>   $$
> S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1 \}.
> $$
>   Show that $f$ is constant.

My attempt is: define a function $g(z) = e^{if(z)}$ and plug some roots of unity in $g,$ but how can I conclude from this?
I know that if $\Omega$ is open, connected and $f(\Omega) \subset \mathbb{R},$ then $f$ is constant.

Comment: Can you can break $\mathbb{D}$ into two open charts and conclude that if it's constant on those charts and where the charts overlap then it must be constant on the entire set? I want to puncture the circle at a single point, conclude it's constant on that open set, then do it again with a different point and then conclude it's constant everywhere.

Comment: The other answers are slick (and correct), but I think I have a from scratch proof that might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ be the open unit ball centered at the origin. Then its closure $\bar{B}$ is the closed unit ball centered at the origin, and its boundary $\partial B$ is the unit circle $S^1$. We are given that $f(\partial B) \subset \Bbb{R}$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial function.

We show that $\partial(f(B)) \subset f(\partial B)$. Since $\bar{B}$ is compact, and the continuous image of a compact set is compact, $f(\bar{B})$ is compact. By the Heine-Borel theorem, $f(\bar{B})$ is closed and bounded. Hence,
$$
B \subset \bar{B} \implies f(B) \subset f(\bar{B}) \implies \overline{f(B)} \subset \overline{f(\bar{B})} = f(\bar{B}).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\overline{f(B)} \subset f(\bar{B}).\tag{$*$}
$$
Now, by definition we have $\partial(f(B)) = \overline{f(B)} \setminus f(B)^o$, where $f(B)^o$ is the interior of $f(B)$. Since polynomial functions are holomorphic, by the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) $f(B)$ is open, so $f(B)^o = f(B)$. Using this and $(*)$, we get
$$
\partial(f(B)) = \overline{f(B)} \setminus f(B)^o \subset f(\bar{B}) \setminus f(B) \subset f(\bar{B} \setminus B) = f(\partial B).
$$

Hence,
$$
\partial(f(B)) \subset f(\partial B) \subset \Bbb{R}.\tag{$\dagger$}
$$

Now, since $f(B) \subset f(\bar{B})$ which is bounded, $f(B)$ is a bounded open subset of $\Bbb{C}$. Therefore, $f(B)$ must have boundary points lying outside $\Bbb{R}$ as well, which contradicts $(\dagger)$. To see why this is true, choose any $z \in f(B)$ and suppose wlog that $\mathrm{Im}(z) \geq 0$. Consider the vertical ray in the upper half plane starting at $z$, given by $\{ z + it : t \geq 0 \}$. Since $f(B)$ is bounded, there exists $t \geq 0$ such that $z+it \not\in f(B)$. Let $s = \inf \{t \geq 0 : z+it \not\in f(B)\}$. Then, $s$ exists and $s > 0$, and the point $z+is$ is a boundary point of $f(B)$ that does not lie on the real axis. (If $\mathrm{Im}(z) \leq 0$, then we consider the vertical ray in the lower half plane starting at $z$ and arrive at a contradiction in a similar manner.)

Thus, we have a contradiction, and hence $f$ must be constant.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can do this from scratch, especially since we are given that $f$ is a polynomial:

Let $\mathbb T$ be the unit circle, and $f$ a polynomial of degree $n$.

For $z=e^{it}$, consider the real number

$f(e^{it})=a_0 +a_1e^{it}+a_2e^{2it}+\cdots a_{n}e^{nit}.$

The imaginary part of this must be equal to zero, so

$Im\ a_0+\sum^{n}_{k=1}(Re\ a_k\sin kt+Im\ a_k\cos kt)=0$.

But now, linear independence of the set $\left \{1, \sin kt,\cos kt \right \}^{n}_{k=1}$  on $\mathbb T$ implies that

$Im\ a_0=a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$ so $f(z)=Re\ a_0$.

Answer (score 3):

If we set
$$
u(x,y)=\mathrm{Im}\,f(x+iy),
$$
then $u$ is a harmonic function, which vanishes on the unit circle. Maximum (together with Minimum) Principle for harmonic function imply that
$$
\max_{x^2+y^2\le 1}{u(x,y)}=\max_{x^2+y^2=1}{u(x,y)}=0
\quad\text{and}\quad
\min_{x^2+y^2\le 1}{u(x,y)}=\min_{x^2+y^2=1}{u(x,y)}=0
$$
Hence, $u\equiv 0$ in the closed unit disk, and hence $u\equiv 0$ everywhere. (Identity Principle.)

Thus $f$ takes only real values, and hence $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

The imaginary part $\text{Im}\;f(z)$ of $f(z)$ is harmonic, and zero on the unit circle, hence by the maximum principle for harmonic functions, we conclude that  $\text{Im}\;f(z)$ is identically zero in the ball.  Thus $f$ is real in the ball.  Of course a non-constant real function cannot have complex derivative at $0$; in particular $f$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: Nice proof but I think it defeats the purpose of the questionbecause I doubt the OP has gotten that far

Comment: If he has not gotten to the maximum principle, I doubt he haa gotten to the open mapping theorem, either.

Comment: Fair enough, but since $f$ is given as a polynomial, it just seems like overkill to bring out the open mapping theorem/max modulus principle. I think you only need linear independence of $\{1,e^{int}\}$ on $\mathbb T.$ I am no expert, though, so if you really do need these bigger guns, please let me know!

Comment: Nice proof using the maximum principle for harminic functions.